# How can I change UIActionsheet button colors?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, uiactionsheet, uicolor

I want to change background colors of UIActionSheet buttons.How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change `UIActionSheet` button colors, apart from adding a destructive button that creates a red option. If you really want custom button colors, try making a custom `UIActionSheet` like so: [custom-uiactionsheet-using-core-animation](http://blog.corywiles.com/custom-uiactionsheet-using-core-animation)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and only clicked together a basic solution.

The core animation approach is superior but that may be simpler

https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDUtils/tree/master/ui/M42ActionSheet%20%5Bios%5D

Disclaimer: mine ;) and also not the coolest code since its from 2010 but it should work fine